# How to record audio from only a specific program on linux?

Tags: linux, audio, audio-recording

Is there a way to record the audio from only a specific program, so that other sounds (e.g. notifications) are not recorded?

I'm running Archlinux with pulseaudio.

Comment: Something like [Jack?](http://jackaudio.org/) with all relative [complex background](http://jackaudio.org/faq/pulseaudio_and_jack.html)

Comment: More way e.g. [the new new way](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/PulseAudio/Examples#The_new_new_way)

Answer (score 3):

You can use pacat which is part of pulseaudio.

First open your application.  THen run pactl list and find your device.  in my example, I will use chrome

snipet:

```
Client #229
Driver: protocol-native.c
    Owner Module: 8
    Properties:
        application.name = "Chrome input"
    native-protocol.peer = "UNIX socket client"
        native-protocol.version = "28"
    application.process.id = "16404"
        application.process.user = "robert"
        application.process.host = "HS"
        application.process.binary = "chrome"
        application.language = "en_US.UTF-8"
    window.x11.display = ":0.0"
        application.process.machine_id = "15d4d55cf80e320acb892977520d0894"
        application.process.session_id = "c1"
```

I'll grab the application name and run pacat.

```
 pacat -r -n "Chrome input" | sox -t raw -r 44100 -s -L -b 16 -c 2 - "output.wav"
```

You can also use pacat to capture from a device, etc.  the pacat man page has some more info

Comment: This looks good! I've never used sox before though.. I get `sox WARN getopt: option \`s' not recognized` when trying to run your example.

Comment: @gandalf3  I'll have to test it before I update my answer, but you can probably do away with sox and just use pacat to write to wav files.  If you want to stream to a compressed format, you can pipe pacat to your favorite encoder.   example: pacat --volume=32768 --format=s16ne --channels=2 --rate=44100 -r -n "Chrome Input"  > /home/[user]/Desktop/chrome.wav